# Add New Relic Trace to non-method type in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, var, trace, newrelic

I currently have New Relic tracking performance of a specific method as follows:

```
  [Transaction(Web = true)]
            public IHttpActionResult List(string companySiteName, [FromUri]DateTime? asOf, [FromUri]string status = "approved")
{...}
```

Since this method is running slowly, I want to get a more detailed view of what is happening internally. I know that adding the `[Trace]` tag to methods within `List`  will do this, but my problem is that all my code within `List` are definitions of variables using Linq and database connections.

Any idea on how to add New Relic Trace to non methods?

(Documentation Pages I used found [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/custom-instrumentation/custom-instrumentation-attributes-net) and [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/custom-instrumentation/introduction-net-custom-instrumentation))

Answer (score 0):

The database work should already be captured, if the database is one we support, so you should be able to see if the database work is causing the slowdown and why on your charts.

If the database work is not causing the slowdown, then, logically, LINQ would be the culprit.  In this case, I would recommend pulling the queries out into their own methods and instrumenting those so which one is to blame.